# regex pattern to match datetime in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a string contains datetimes, I am trying to split the string based on the datetime occurances,

```
data="2018-03-14 06:08:18, he went on \n2018-03-15 06:08:18, lets play"
```

what I am doing,

```
out=re.split('^(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])$',data)
```

what I get

```
["2018-03-14 06:08:18, he went on 2018-03-15 06:08:18, lets play"]
```

What I want:

```
["2018-03-14 06:08:18, he went on","2018-03-15 06:08:18, lets play"]
```

Comment: What is the Python version?

Comment: python version is 3.6.3

Comment: Can there be cases when there is no whitespace between the items? Can we assume we want to split with at least 1 whitespace followed with a date?

Comment: Well, I meant to suggest something like [`r'\s+(?=(?:(?:20)?[01]?[0-9])-(?:1[0-2]|0?[0-9])-(?:[0-2]?[0-9]|3[01]))'`](https://regex101.com/r/k339Yt/1) with split.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to split with at least 1 whitespace followed with a date like pattern, thus, you may use

```
re.split(r'\s+(?=\d{2}(?:\d{2})?-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\b)', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k339Yt/2)

**Details**

- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?=\d{2}(?:\d{2})?-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\b)` - a *positive lookahead* that makes sure,  that immediately to the left of the current location, there are

  - `\d{2}(?:\d{2})?` - 2 or 4 digits
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
  - `-\d{1,2}` - again a hyphen and 1 or 2 digits
  - `\b`  -  a word boundary (if not necessary, remove it, or replace with `(?!\d)` in case you may have dates glued to letters or other text)

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/9ybxff):

```
import re
rex = r"\s+(?=\d{2}(?:\d{2})?-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\b)"
s = "2018-03-14 06:08:18, he went on 2018-03-15 06:08:18, lets play"
print(re.split(rex, s))
# => ['2018-03-14 06:08:18, he went on', '2018-03-15 06:08:18, lets play']
```

**NOTE** If there can be no whitespace before the date, in Python 3.7 and newer you may use `r"\s*(?=\d{2}(?:\d{2})?-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\b)"` (note the `*` quantifier with `\s*` that will allow zero-length matches). For older versions, you will need to use a solution [as @blhsing suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51395834/3832970) or install [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and use `r"(?V1)\s*(?=\d{2}(?:\d{2})?-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\b)"` with `regex.split`.

Answer (score 4):

`re.split` is meant for cases where you have a certain delimiter pattern. Use `re.findall` with a lookahead pattern instead:

```
import re
data="2018-03-14 06:08:18, he went on \n2018-03-15 06:08:18, lets play"
d = r'\d{4}-\d?\d-\d?\d (?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]'
print(re.findall(r'{0}.*?(?=\s*{0}|$)'.format(d), data, re.DOTALL))
```

This outputs:

```
['2018-03-14 06:08:18, he went on', '2018-03-15 06:08:18, lets play']
```

Comment: Note that a lazy dot with a lookahead might be too resource consuming since the lookahead pattern is checked after each char after the subpattern before the lazy dot. If the requirement is to split with 1 or more whitespaces that are followed with something like a date, [`re.split(r'\s+(?=\d{2}(?:\d{2})?-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\b)', s)`](https://regex101.com/r/k339Yt/2) might be a better choice.

Comment: @blhsing it returns only the last occurance in my actual data

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew your solution is working fine, can you post that as a answer

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Agreed. I had initially thought about using split with a lookahead pattern but didn't realize the OP did not want to include the white space at the end of each sub-string anyway, in which case your solution is better indeed.

Comment: @pyd Can you update your question with your actual data then?

Comment: @pyd I see. In case you have a `'\n'` in the string you just need to add an `re.DOTALL` flag to `findall`. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @blhsing

Comment: @pyd You're welcome. In fact, if there's always a `'\n'` before each date/time, you might as well use `str.split('\n')`` to get what you want.