# separating multiple text logs printed in a single line using reg exp

Tags: python, python-3.x

Each log that our program produces has the following format:

```
2021-08-04:12.55.51.965438904: bla bla bla bla

2021-08-04:12.55.51.965493516: bla bla bla bla

2021-08-04:12.55.52.073093436: bla bla bla bla
```

where "bla bla" could be any combinations of text/number. There are some cases that multiple logs are printed into a single line, like this:

```
2021-08-04:12.55.51.965438904: bla bla bla bla2021-08-04:12.55.51.965493516: bla bla bla bla2021-08-04:12.55.52.073093436: bla bla bla bla
```

How can we separate each logs from such line?
I started with this snippet,

```
import re

string = "2021-08-04:12.55.51.965438904: bla bla bla bla2021-08-04:12.55.51.965493516: bla bla bla bla2021-08-04:12.55.52.073093436: bla bla bla bla"

reg_exp = re.compile(r"(\d+-\d+-\d+:\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)")
for match in reg_exp.finditer(string):
    print(match.group(1))
```

However, I need to include the "bla bla bla bla" too.
The snipper prints the timestamps only.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have written?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation, but I suggest `regex` be added as a tag.

Comment: this will help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51395590/regex-pattern-to-match-datetime-in-python

Answer (score 3):

## [See this answer instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68811016/11108026)

#### Warning

It's a bit of code smell to have to do this. It looks like one of the logging functions isn't printing a newline after each log, which it should.

I recommend finding the culprit and fixing the problem at it's source, but until then, this should work.

#### Code

It can definitely be done without regular expressions, but I've followed your lead here and just changed the regex in your snippet:

```py
import re

string = "2021-08-04:12.55.51.965438904: bla bla bla bla2021-08-04:12.55.51.965493516: bla bla bla bla2021-08-04:12.55.52.073093436: bla bla bla bla"

reg_exp = re.compile(r"(\d{4}-.+?)(?=(\d{4}-|$))")
for match in reg_exp.finditer(string):
    print(match.group(1))
```

#### Explanation

This regex matches four digits & hyphen, then anything else until it finds either: another four digits & hyphen, or the end of the line.

```regex
(\d{4}-.+?)(?=(\d{4}-|$))
```

Here's a permalink to the expression being tested on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/D20L0z/1).

#### Safer Versions*

Just paste any of these regexes in the snippet above to use instead.

```regex
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}:.+?)(?=(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}:|$))
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/W6Noak/1): This one checks to make sure the entire prefix is correct. It should look like: `yyyy-mm-dd:`. Year, month and day should all be digits or `\d` so we get: `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}:`

```regex
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}:.+?)(?=(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}:|[\n\r]*$))
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/AE8kk3/1): This one will still match the string even if there are extra newlines printed at the end. It changes the `$` to `[\n\r]*$`.

*If anyone can think of any other ways to make the regex safer, please feel free to add it here!*

<sub>*Added by OP's request in comment below.</sub>

Comment: If the "bla bla bla" contains a four digit number, then logic will pick it up as the beginning of the next line. For example, 2021-08-04:12.55.51.965493516: bla bla 8080 bla bla. Shouldn't we use the reg exp for year, month, day instead?

Comment: That's true, although it'd have to be a 4 digit number *and* a dash right after it like `blah bla bla 8080- bla bla`. I was trying to simplify the regex, but there are a few things we can do to make it extra safe. I'll work on editing in a safer version for you right now. But don't forget to also look into fixing the faulty print statement at the source!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got the question correctly because I see a pretty complex regex solution (and I fear I might be wrong), but why don't you try to use `re.split` and then combine every 2 elements from the split instead?

Something along the lines

```py
import re
from itertools import starmap
from operator import add

string = "2021-08-04:12.55.51.965438904: bla bla bla bla2021-08-04:12.55.51.965493516: bla bla bla bla2021-08-04:12.55.52.073093436: bla bla bla bla"

reg_exp = re.compile(r"(\d+-\d+-\d+:\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+: )")
logs = reg_exp.split(string)
# Group and zip every two elements
logs = zip(logs[1::2], logs[2::2])
# Add elements
logs = starmap(add, logs)
# Cast it to list if necessary, here I don't do it
for log in logs:
    print(log)
```

prints

```
2021-08-04:12.55.51.965438904: bla bla bla bla
2021-08-04:12.55.51.965493516: bla bla bla bla
2021-08-04:12.55.52.073093436: bla bla bla bla
```

Comment: I'm just seeing this. It's a great idea to use split, much better than my initial approach. But see [my new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68811016/11108026), I think it's cleaner!

Comment: I personally try to avoid lookaheads etc but whatever floats your boat. The main principle is that re.split is simpler than trying to find a pure regex solution. I don't get why would you create an alternative solution using re.split. There are probably 1000.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying here. Mind elaborating? I have a feeling the comments will turn into a discussion thread so feel free to ping me in [the regex room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex-regular-expressions).

Comment: Nah I am too bored to discuss too much about it. I am saying that there is literally no reason to provide an alternate answer with `re.split` since there is already one. If in every question, this scenario happened we would have 102930192301 answers with the same method and slightly different solutions each time improving on it. This is why comments are for, so we don't have 102930192301 similar answers. I usually try to avoid answering questions with answers similar to what I have in mind cause I find it stupid to create alternative similar answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler approach than [the original answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68810497/11108026).
This revised approach is based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68810075/separating-multiple-text-logs-printed-in-a-single-line-using-reg-exp/68810497#comment121608508_68810075) and [the linked SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51395590/regex-pattern-to-match-datetime-in-python).

It splits the string on every occurrence of `yyyy-mm-dd:`, or more precisely `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}:`.
The resulting list has an extra empty string at the beginning from the splitting, so we ignore it with the `[1:]`.

```py
import re
regex = r"(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}:)"
string = "2021-08-04:12.55.51.965438904: bla bla bla bla2021-08-04:12.55.51.965493516: bla bla bla bla2021-08-04:12.55.52.073093436: bla bla bla bla"
for log in re.split(regex, string)[1:]:
    print(log)
```